# VB.NET custom web browser that only allows certain websites and it's webpages

Tags: vb.net, browser

The task is to create a custom web browser using VB.net 2005 Webbrowser control. 
This browser must only be able to access webpages from selected websites.

For example: if the allowed is only gmail, then any webpage that involves gmail.com will be allowed (ie even if the logged user changes, it's okay cause it's still gmail). If the user clicks on an advertisement that will lead him/her to leave gmail, the browser will ignore it and return him to gmail.com

I have prepared a combobox that will act as the addressbar of the webbrowser. The allowed websites so far are mail.yahoo.com and gmail.com.

I would like some advice on how I can achieve this. 
Perhaps there is a simple solution, so that I won't have to create a customizable browser? problem is, our leader strongly wishes to block all these other sites, and wishes a custom browser that a user can't fiddle with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Blocking internet access by building a custom browser?  Psh.  Good luck with that.  If you can easily rig up a web browser, so can any number of other people.  Hell, thanks to the existence of basically that same web browser control you're looking to use, [even Word and Excel can browse the web.](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/10/05/webbrowser-control/)  If you want any hope of success, forget the client side; route everything through a web proxy and tell it what you want to block.

Comment: Of course, the real solution would be to have a talk with the users in question, and tell them to stop wasting time at work.  :) But something tells me your boss is trying to solve people problems with software.  (For reference, that hardly ever works out as well as he imagines it will.)

Comment: This is not something you should try to do in a custom browser. Tell your "leader" to Google "web proxy".

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I guess the gameplan is that this Custom Browser is included to a program that also can kill the taskbar, to also prevent unauthorized use of other applications (we kill the taskbar while the browser is running, and limit the programs the user can access via Process.Start) 

Also, for web proxy, you need a separate server, correct? What if we wish to be cost effective?

Comment: A web proxy is just a piece of software that can run on any server. You don't need a seperate server for that.

Comment: @Malky.Kid: You shouldn't need a new server.  Might need to buy some software, but there should be open stuff out there that's workable.  Frankly, though, you're talking about false economy here; the alternative is only cheaper if your time is worthless.  Quite a bit of time and effort is going to go into this brokenness before it's over with...and even if you're on salary, that time is still being taken up by this as opposed to something worthwhile. Even if the company did end up getting another server, it'd save money by not having you waste your time on an inherently flawed idea.